# I have someone that is controlling my phone from another device

Tags: mobile, phone

How do I stop somebody from controlling my phone from another device and taking my data and stealing my information?

Comment: That was short. Can you provide more details of what's happening, how do you know that someone is controlling your phone etc...

Comment: Well there's a whole bunch of things that have been happening actually on my main page is no longer my main page it goes to roaming and there's things being controlled there's

Comment: Here's just a few to list messages or conversations that are all the sudden being pulled up but I haven't been in that conversation for a few days or in my cashews it explains that my information is being computed there is stuff block that I can no longer go into there is internet pages that I've never been on that have to do with tracking blocking encryption

Comment: n taking battery running  out navigation tracking put on my phone well all of a sudden have internet Pages or things like that that I've never hooked up before sites about tracking as well as spyware and things like that never looked at that are coming up, there is Computing of my information when I go into cashe it says computting  or apps that I've never added Now on my phone or apps that list whole number of things that you can control from another device that cost money that I've never ever

Comment: Shoot sorry I repeated I'm using talk to text

Comment: When I do some leg work and go into all of my programs and applications there is a bunch that I haven't added but it also or ones that I have added that also show that there is something new with them or their repeated and there's a there's Bell service showing which I am not on and things that I cannot erase applications I cannot erase her have control of

Comment: I believe it's my roommate that I live with he's a little bit Head Over Heels but there's been a lot of other Sneaky's things before this that make me believe that it's him also he's on Bell service and I do use his wife I even when my WiFi is shut off I'm still seem to have problems I'm basically every time that he's away from the house

Comment: I wouldn't doubt if you can even see these messages as of now

Comment: I tried deleting a bunch of apps that don't make sense to me or that I didn't put on I've tried for stopping them I've tried clearing cache and data I've tried throwing out the apps and that doesn't work or they're just still on my phone the very next day my front page that I usually use when it has all the icons on it and applications on it on my front page all the sudden goes to the second page and I cannot change it back that's how I originally know that at that point than then he's on and watching or listening or controlling it's pretty freaky and quite the violation of privacy

Comment: I'm just not very tech-savvy and have tried everything that I can possibly muster up to avoid this without wiping all of my information off of my phone

Comment: Geez sorry for the chapter book Iam  just completely overwhelmed and really wanting the privacy of my information  as well as my documentation  and sense of self no being altered anymore want violation of my privacy and Communications to stop being altered and messed with it's like super creepy and I just feel in the end there is some sort of malicious and vindictive reason for this person to be doing all this and I don't want to Leave Myself open to get in a bad situation or have this person ruin anything for me in the future

Comment: The problem seems kinda convoluted. I'd suggest just a factory reset. Make backups of your contacts and other files you value first though.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of treating the comments as a forum.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, backup your stuff and go with a *factory* reset. After that, update the system on your device and follow a few points:

- encrypt your device
- use an AV software
- avoid installing not trusted apps
- use VPN (avoid free ones, **because sometimes free ones are the most expensive**) when you are browsing over Wi-Fi
- make sure that your phone is safe physically
- educate yourself about security in general (avoiding hacker tactics)

Comment: @Jae Also, if you have an android phone; you can use Noroot Firewall which create a local VPN, then let you see all network logs, deny/accept for specific application in case you may find unfamiliar app, and you can test rules to find out if a specific app installed on your phone without your knowledge.